# VMware produces no output when using RDP to connect to the host

Tags: rhel, vmware, xrdp

I recently decided to switch to Linux at work, but I still require Windows and sometimes work remotely. When using Windows as a host this wasn't a big deal because I could RDP into my machine and launch VMWare and work out of Virtual Machines when needed.

Now I am using RHEL 8.5 as my Host with VMWare Workstation 16.2.1.
I have XRDP setup and can RDP into my RHEL box, but when I try to boot up a VM in VMWare over my RDP session, I get no graphical output from VMWare. (See picture)

Even though VMWare sits there 'Waiting for connection' the VM is actually running and booted up, just no output is being produced.

[image: VMWare being silly]

I am using XRDP to create a new xfce session upon connecting. (Disregard the picture showing GNOME 3, I have changed the configuration but the problem still exists with xfce. Likely an issue with RDP/XVNC itself?)

Ideally I want to be able to RDP into my RHEL host instead of RDP directly into the VM, as I work with multiple VMs at any given time.

EDIT:

If I am interpreting this correctly, my RDP session is using software rendering, while my Plasma session (no RDP, physically at the device) is using hardware rendering. Is there a way to fix this?

[image: no RDP]

[image: RDP session]

Comment: Does your RHEL host have a graphical front-end? If you login at its console directly does RDP to the VMware guest work?

Comment: Yes, my RHEL host is using SDDM as the 'login window' and Plasma X11 as the default desktop. For RDP sessions I have configured it to start an xfce session.

I am able to VNC into the Guest using the settings in VMWare, but I cannot RDP directly to the Guest, as it attempts to RDP into my RHEL host. VNC does produce output but relies on the VM being on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to build `xorgxrdp` from source, as the one available from official repos (codeready/epel/appstream) do not have glamor support.

You can choose to install `xrdp` from the available repos - it is the same version as available on github. You will however need to download the source and compile `xorgxrdp` against it.

Assuming you have a typical X window system installation, you will still need to install a few packages. As this is specific to Enterprise Linux, I will post the package names for EL, though they are available on other version such as arch and debian.

Install the proper build tools:

```
nasm
libtool
pkgconf
automake
autoconf
```

Make sure the following packages are installed:

```
xorg-x11-proto-devel
xorg-x11-server-devel
mesa-libGL-devel
mesa-libEGL*
mesa-libGLU*
mesa-libGLw*
mesa-libGLw-devel
mesa-libgbm*
mesa-libgbm-devel
mesa-libglapi*
libepoxy-devel
```

*at the bare minimum you will need the **devel** packages.

save the following to a convenient location

```
git clone https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp
git clone https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xorgxrdp
```

navigate to the `xorgxrdp` folder and perform the following commands

```
./bootstrap
./configure XRDP_CFLAGS=-I/path/to/xrdp/common --enable-glamor 
make
sudo make install
```

Pay attention to the output generated by `./configure` if it fails. It may require additional packages to be installed, though it will tell you the actual package name instead of saying 'dri' not found.

Once you have completed this step, uncomment the following lines in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`

```
[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20
```

Restart the xrdp service.

Connect to the host with an RDP client. (you may need to reboot if the session closes immediately after connecting, or at least I ran into this issue.)

And enjoy a GPU accelerated RDP session.

[image: GPU Accelerated xRDP!]

[image: glxgears in action]

It is worth noting that this performance will not be the same as using RDP to connect to a Windows device, but it is much better than using software rendering.

I am not going to go in to details about security and reconnecting to the same session/connecting to a session that already exists, or enabling audio pass through as there are other topics on various forums that cover this quite well.

Final note: I am not sure if this works with NVidia cards. The arch wiki leads me to think that is the case, however the git repo says nothing about it.